# Bulk email mailing software with the capability to write details back to MySQL database

Tags: email, mysql, marketing

We're looking at replacing our current software Arial Software's "Email Marketing Director" (now discontinued). Details:

- The database of email addresses and other details is stored in a MySQL database. Emails are expected to be added weekly, so the software should send only to new addresses.
- We are required to track the date and time we send each email. This needs to be stored in the database.
- We need to store whether emails bounce back in the database (hard bounces)
- Unsubscribe requests should be handled by updating a column in the database to mark the email as unsubscribed, which we can then send back to our client.
- Checks with spam filters to see if it's detected as spam would be nice.
- We can't host the data with a 3rd party company, it needs to be downloadable software to run locally (Windows).

So far, all the software we've found will do much of what we want, but either with an internal database only, or will only read from the MySQL connection, not update anything.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.